# How to inject a mapper within a mapper

Tags: java, hibernate, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct in my project.
I have an entity object in which i would like to map to my domain object. The entity object comes from running a SQL query.

Inside the entity object, it has a field in which it contains a List of another type (due to a 1 to many mapping). This is my mapping:

```
        @Mapping(target = "listOfDomainB", source = "entityA.list", qualifiedByName = "mapList")
    DomainA map(EntityA entityA);

    @Named("mapList")
    default List<DomainB> mapList(List<EntityB> entityB) {
        return entityB.stream()
                .map(EntityB -> new EntityB()
                        .name(EntityB.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

It does the job but this mapper is being used in my service class (via constructor injection... private final) and when I am writing my unit test for that service class, i am not mocking the mapper as I want to use the implementation of the mapper. But the unit test fails as it cannot access the `default` method `mapList` because it's not in the implementation class. The implementation class calls this default method but when doing (.toCallRealMethod() on the mapper mock i.e. `when(mapperImpl.map()).thenCallRealMethod()`, the impl class doesn't call the `mapList`)

Any idas?

Comment: First you say that you are not mocking the mapper, but then you say you are using a mapper mock. Which is it? In my experience you don't need to mock mappers if you use constructor injection (also in generated mappers if necessary). Just add the `target/generated-sources/annotations` folder as source root and you can directly use the generated implementation classes.

Comment: technically i am mocking but calling the real method via `.thenCallRealMethod()`. I am currently injecting the mocks in the service using `@InjectMocks` so i am using `@Mock MyMapperImpl mapper` in my class